# IE 11 first time ajax call working second not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

In IE 11, I am using xml as my data for send and return data as xml,when i am loading my page first time it comes but after when i call ajax call based on any event it show me error as:

```
{readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Se..."}
```

same code for the Mozilla Firefox, it works fine & return proper result as what i want.

and for that my code is:

```
$.ajax({
     async: true,
    cache: false,
    url             : url,
    type            :   'POST',
    precessData     :   true,
    contentType     :   "application/xml",
    data            :   data,
    dataType        : "text",
    error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

 }).done(function(res){
 console.log(res);

 });
```

Comment: Any error appeared in IE Developer Tool, especially security errors?

Comment: no the error or msg i got is mentioned in  question.

Comment: If I were you, I will `console.log(data)` to see whether 2nd call post data is correct or not

Comment: yes i put this line and it shows me as the expected result what i want as this data as input xml.

Comment: And is the server-side stable & check unique connection (blocks 2nd connection from same IP, etc)

Comment: What is the logic of your Serverside code? Did you try to output a static not changing XML to test?

Comment: yes with static xml it works fine but when i modify this xml based on event it is not working..

i am using xml text and append function of jquery for this.

Answer (score 0):

"Internal server error" means that the thing you're getting data from is having problems.

The issue is not in your client code.

Comment: I have no idea.  Whatever the difference is is within the backend code, which you have not provided.